# Comparing rows in the same table in PostgreSQL based on one field updates

Tags: sql, postgresql

So this is a kind of complex SQL query, and I want to do it in an optimal way.

I want to get the list of customers in the DB that withdraw all money they have in the bank and stop using the bank and also the time that stops using the bank is also important for me. What I mean by stop using the bank is they didn't deposit money after they withdraw it. So the deposit is still 0.

Here is what I have done so far;

The customer table is;

```
   customer_id deposit  ts 
    101        44        2021-09-30 10:12:19+00
    101        0         2021-09-30 09:12:19+00
    101        65        2021-09-29 09:12:19+00  
    100        0         2021-10-31 14:12:19+00  
    100        0         2021-10-30 13:12:19+00  
    100        0         2021-09-30 10:12:19+00  
    100        21        2021-09-29 10:12:19+00
    104        54        2021-09-27 10:12:19+00
```

so here we can see that customer_id:101 withdraws all its money at some point(65 -> 0), but then deposits the money back.(0 -> 44) So it is still using the bank.
But so far customer_id:100 seems like it stopped using the bank.  at 2021-09-30 10:12:19+00, it withdraws money, and when we look at the latest row that belongs to customer:100, it is still 0.

So as a result I only want to get the customer_id:100;

```
   customer_id deposit      ts                     pre_deposit
      100        0         2021-09-30 10:12:19+00  21
```

So what I have done so  far can be seen here;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4aef7/1/0

```
select distinct on (customer_id) *
from 
(
 select customer_id, deposit, ts, 
        lead(deposit) over w as pre_deposit, 
        lead(ts) over w as pre_ts 
 from t
 window w as (partition by customer_id order by ts desc)
) t 
where pre_deposit != 0 AND deposit = 0 
order by customer_id, ts desc;
```

but this also returns the customer_id:101, because at some point the deposit became 0.
but the only row that I want to get is customer_id:100.

So how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You query is close, but your `where` criteria stills allows a later date to contain a non zero deposit amount as it compares the data only from the 2 initial rows. To see what is happening lets just look at a portion of your query for customer 101.

```
 select row_number() over()        -- added for discussion
      , customer_id, deposit, ts  
      , lead(deposit) over w as pre_deposit 
      , lead(ts) over w as pre_ts 
   from t
  where customer_id = 101
 window w as (partition by customer_id order by ts desc);
```

This query produces the following (and that is temporary generated by your full query):

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
| rn | customer_id | deposit |              ts               | pre_deposit |            pre_ts             |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 |         101 |      44 | 2021-09-30 05:12:19.000 -0500 |           0 | 2021-09-30 04:12:19.000 -0500 |
|  2 |         101 |       0 | 2021-09-30 04:12:19.000 -0500 |          65 | 2021-09-29 04:12:19.000 -0500 |
|  3 |         101 |      65 | 2021-09-29 04:12:19.000 -0500 |             |                               |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

Now look at rn2. It contains the vales from itself, and the pre values from rn3.  Rn2 is the row that is eventually selected. Notice it clearly satisfies your `where` criteria. The problem is the existence of row 1. Because rn1 is there is reason to exclude. That exclusion is missing. That exclusion needs added to the `where` clause. Need to make sure that any such row does **not exist**.    (See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8938a/9))

```
with test as 
     ( select t.* 
            , lag(deposit) over w as pre_deposit 
            , lag(ts) over w as pre_ts 
         from t
       window w as (partition by customer_id order by ts)
     ) 
select distinct on (customer_id) *
  from test t1
 where t1.deposit = 0  
   and not exists ( select null 
                      from test t2
                     where t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id
                       and t2.deposit > 0 
                       and t2.ts > t1.ts
                   ) ;
```

**NOTE:** I ran the demo in Postgres 9.3, the same as yours. I assume that is the version you are running. However, that version reached End-of-List in November 2018. I would highly recommend you update version if you are actually using 9.3.